# Importing node_module css file to NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mapbox-autocomplete with my nextJS app. I'm receiving a problem though when I attempt to actually use it. I get the following

error:"./node_modules/react-mapbox-autocomplete/index.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/css-npm
Location: node_modules/react-mapbox-autocomplete/index.js

Now trying to do some research into this, I saw that NextJS supports importing css from node_modules in _app.js, which I tried. but i'm still getting the error! :( Here's my _app.js:

```
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import 'react-mapbox-autocomplete/index.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
  <Layout><Component {...pageProps} /></Layout>)
}

export default MyApp
```

Hoping one of you can help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reviewing the documentation for this library further. In their README.md they tell you how to use both styling and the component itself.

```
import MapboxAutocomplete from 'react-mapbox-autocomplete';
```

You also need to actually use their component somewhere like so.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <MapboxAutocomplete />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

From there you can override their styles by modifying the classes that they make note of here: https://github.com/localvore-today/react-mapbox-autocomplete#styling

Comment: You're welcome, if this works for you please accept as an answer @sylargaf :)